# Greyhound from NYC to DC

Tags: tickets, buses, new-york-city

Do Greyhound buses from NYC to DC depart from Port Authority or do they depart from the Greyhound station near the George Washington bridge?

Comment: This was something you couldn't find out with a sample itinerary on the Greyhound website?

Comment: @user71659 Only if you know where to look, and it isn't entirely obvious.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's still a basic expectation of Stack Exchange that the OP demonstrate some initial research effort; "This question does not show any research effort" is literally the first criterion for downvoting. This isn't a matter of digging around in a map room at the library, but a web search on "Greyhound station New York" which turns up [something pretty useful](https://locations.greyhound.com/bus-stations/search?city=New+York&state=NY&zip=&q=New+York%2C+NY) at the top of my results.

Comment: @choster How did you find that particular page useful? I also saw that, and was disappointed precisely because it was _not_ useful for answering this question.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in the address details on Greyhound.com.

Greyhound's main station in New York is still *Port Authority Bus Terminal*.

Greyound.com treats each stop as a "city."  The "main" stop is the city: [*New York, NY **is** Port Authority Bus Terminal*](https://locations.greyhound.com/bus-stations/us/new-york/new-york/bus-station-151239). If you want to depart from secondary stops like George Washington Bridge (or Brooklyn) you need to choose them as the search origin: e.g. *New York GW Bridge, NY*:

[image: Greyhound search field]

Searching for *New York GW Bridge, NY* you'll see different buses than those from *New York, NY*, prooving the results you're looking at aren't for that station.

At [Busbud](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules-results/dr5reg/dqcjqb?outbound_date=2019-02-27&adults=1) our searches return all stations in the city. You'll see we differentiate between the two stations, and that the vast majority of buses leave Port Authority like you'd expect. We're leveraging the data we're getting directly from Greyhound.

[image: Busbud NYC-DC]

Comment: That's interesting. When I select New York, NY on Greyhound I only get departures from GW Bridge, none from Port Authority at all. It was quite surprising.

Answer (score 4):

Selecting an itinerary on the Greyhound web site for [your desired city pair](https://locations.greyhound.com/bus-routes/destination/new-york-ny/washington-dc) will allow you to see the location of the bus stations involved.

For example: Click View Itinerary, then place your mouse over the name of the city, and the terminal information appears:

[image: Greyhound booking showing bus terminal address]

For all the schedules I looked at, it appears that *all* of them depart from the GW Bridge terminal. I could not find any departing from Port Authority from a quick look around.

Comment: I'm surprised. For those who want to take a bus from midtown to DC, though, within a few blocks of either the Port Authority Bus Terminal or Pennsylvania Station.

Comment: There's always BoltBus and an ever-changing selection of Chinatown buses that happen to pick up in midtown. I have no idea when GLI moved buses out of Port Authority, as it's been many years since I took GLI in or out of NYC, but I can guess why; it's freaking crowded down there.

Comment: It's proabably also quicker to get across the Hudson on the George Washington Bridge than through the Lincoln Tunnel, though before I-278 was built that wasn't nearly as likely to be true.